# Are there any "gotchas" when updating the Paypal API signature in s2Member in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, api, paypal, signature

I'm using s2Member in my Wordpress site. I want to update the Paypal API signature. Before I do that I'm trying to find out if there are any issues or problems that might come about if I do this.

Comment: Are you switching *between* PayPal accounts? That is, does this new signature belong to an entirely new PayPal account? Or are you updating to a new signature generated for the *same* PayPal account being used previously? That is a key difference.

Answer (score 0):

If the new API username + API password + API signature belongs to the same PayPal account you were using previously (one easy way to tell is that the API username should not change) --- then no, there are no gotchas. Just make sure to update it everywhere at once, if there are multiple systems that use the old signature.

If the new API username + API password + API signature belong to a *different* PayPal account, the new account will not be able to manage any recurring or reference transaction information created on the PayPal side for the previous account.